# Kentico workflow Pre-Edit steps

Tags: workflow, kentico

I would like to automatically send 2 emails when the page is created. Those pages are being created automatically after some user's action (filling the form). 
It seems that *Edit* step is the initial step of Kentico workflow's but I haven't found such info in a documentation. In my example email is being sent after page changes status from edit to published. But nothing that is before *Edit* step seems to be working. Any ideas how to achieve that ? I mean I'd like to send email after page is created - before or on *Edit* step.

[Sample workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La89j.jpg)

Comment: Out of interest, how are you creating the pages when the form is submitted?

Comment: I have a custom web part and the form is really an 'Alternative form' build on Page Type. This custom web part is rendering form based on this alternative form and on submit it is creating pages based on this Page Type.

Comment: Ah, I see - that explains why you can't just hook into some code that creates the pages.  Looks like your going to need a global event handler then.  Is that some thing you're able to do?

Answer (score 1):

Wojtek, I'm not aware of a way to begin a workflow *before* the *Edit* step.  Edit is a source step, so this is where your workflow is starting; I do not think your two previous actions ever execute.

In my opinion, your best bet is to either hook into [Global events](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events) when you create the pages or send the emails in the code that creates the pages if possible (I'm not sure how you're doing that part).

**Update:** Looking at the [Configuring workflows](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-workflows) page on DevNet implies that workflow and versioning only begins once the document has been created and is in the *edit* stage.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to add additional steps, edit is the most basic one, usually you have them edit them as a step between "edit" and "published" that you need to approve.

If you want an email on creation or whenever someone touches a page, you can hook into the global events (such as the CMS.document create after our update before) and use the api to send out an email.

If you need some code sample just tell me.

Comment: My sample workflow can be seen in the attached image in the original question. it seems that additional steps that are after *Edit* step are working correctly. I was trying to avoid global events...